# CSS - Div inside a Div

Tags: css

I currently have the following code.

```
<div id="1">
 <div id="2">
  <div id="3">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But I cant seem to figure out how I select the div 3 (??).
Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you need to do to the div? Do you mean access it with css or jquery?

Answer (score 5):

Outside of HTML5 an `id` beginning with a number is invalid HTML; however with CSS you could, ordinarily, select that div with the following:

As posted by [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128956/82548), the `#3` `id`-based selector in this answer is wrong, the `#3` needs to be escaped to `#\33` (though I'll explain no further (see his answer!), to avoid shameless plagiarism/repetition)

```
#3 {
    /* CSS */
}
```

This approach uses an `id`-based selector (only *one* element in the document may use a given `id`, so this is a unique identifier), and is the id-name prefaced with the `#` sign.

The following, however, *is* still valid:

```
div > div > div {
    /* CSS */
}
```

This approach uses the immediate child `>` combinator, and will select a `div` that is the direct child of a `div` (no intervening elements between the two) which is, itself, the immediate child of another `div` element.

References:

- [CSS Selectors, Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/).
- [CSS Selectors, Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).
- [CSS Selectors, Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Comment: `div div div` can't be used why?

Comment: It can; I didn't say that *only* those in the answer were available/valid.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `[id="3"] {}`

Answer (score 2):

When you have an identifier that starts with a digit, you have to use a character escape to write the CSS rule to match it:

```
#\33 { ... }
```

The `33` is the hexadecimal code for the character `3`.

If possible, you should avoid having an id that is a number. Using it gets complicated, both from CSS and from Javascript.

Comment: I knew that there were 'issues' with implementing numbers as the first character of `id`s, I hadn't realised that they needed to be escaped. +1, and thank you! Do you have a reference for the escapes/hex character codes (I could Google, but I thought you might have something in your bookmarks, maybe...)?